# TINYMCE: Add component to Insert image dialog

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-ui, tinymce, less

I want to add input-text below `input-text:Source` in image dialog.

In `Less` / TINYMCE, where does the css file define image dialog UI?

HTML:

```
<textarea id="my_editor"></textarea>

<iframe id="form_target" name="form_target" style="display:none"></iframe>

<form id="my_form" action="/upload/" target="form_target" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" style="width:0px;height:0;overflow:hidden">
  <input name="image" type="file" onchange="$('#my_form').submit();this.value='';">
</form>
```

jQuery:

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: '#my_editor',
    plugins: ["image"],
    file_browser_callback: function(field_name, url, type, win) {
        if(type=='image') $('#my_form input').click();
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/SjJh7/3/

Answer (score 0):

The UI for the Insert Image dialog is in the `image` plugin.  You can extend that plugin code to add additional fields to the form.

In TinyMCE 4.3.10 look for the comment:

```
// General settings shared between simple and advanced dialogs
```

to see where these are added in `plugin.js`.

Comment: I have to a dialog and I want to show it by clicking browse button. But the issue happen, the dialog does not focus. I try to use  tinymce.activeEditor.windowManager.open but does not work